# Java Codelab Logical error

Tags: java

Could someone explain why i'm getting logical error.
The output should be 
Enter·runner·1·name:·Enter·runner·1·time·(in·minutes):·Enter·runner·2·name:·Enter·runner·2·time·(in·minutes):·Enter·runner·3·name:·Enter·runner·3·time·(in·minutes):·Runner3↵
Runner1↵
Runner2↵

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Runners {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double  t1,
            t2,
            t3;



    System.out.print("Enter runner 1 name:");
    String name1;
    name1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter runner 1 time (in minutes):");
    String time1;
    time1 = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print(" Enter runner 2 name:");
    String name2;
    name2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter runner 2 time (in minutes):");
    String time2;
    time2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print(" Enter runner 3 name:");
    String name3;
    name3 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter runner 3 time (in minutes):");
    String time3;
    time3 = keyboard.nextLine();


    t1 = Double.parseDouble(time1);
    t2 = Double.parseDouble(time2);
    t3 = Double.parseDouble(time3);




    if(t1 > t2 && t1 > t3){
        if(t2>t3){
            System.out.print(" "+ name3 + "\n"+ name2 + "\n" + name1+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" "+ name2 + "\n" + name3 + "\n" + name1+ "\n");
        }
    }
    else if(t2>t1 && t2>t3){
        if(t1>t3){
            System.out.print(" " + name3 + "\n" + name1 + "\n" + name2+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name3 + "\n" + name2+ "\n");
        }
    }
    else if(t3>t2 && t3>t1){
        if(t2>t1){
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name2 + "\n" + name3+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" " + name2 + "\n" + name1 + "\n" + name3+ "\n");
        }
    }
    else if(t3==t2 && t3==t1){
        if(t2>t1){
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name2 + "\n" + name3+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name2 + "\n" + name3 + "\n");
        }




}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear can you elaborate

Comment: The prompt is:11. Running the Race
Write a program  that asks for the names  of three runners and the time, in minutes, it took
each of them to finish a race. The program  should display the names  of the runners in the
order that they finished.   I have to make the output exactly the same as the I posted above and when I post it,  I get a logical error. It says the contents of my standard output are incorrect.

Comment: There is no logic error? It outputs exactly as it should. With the first place finisher first, then second, then third.

Comment: I have no idea either, codelab keeps telling me that I have a logic error..

Comment: Only thing I can tell you is the print out format is not good. You have spaces where there is no need for spaces especially if you are just moving to the next line anyway.

Comment: I intentionally added them because the output requires them that way. Maybe I am misunderstanding something but my other projects all required it the same way...

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer to the same question and poked around with the code in this example. There was a logical problem at the end. The AND in line 67 should be an OR. You can't have a condition of 1 being equal to 2 and 2 being equal to 3 and then ask if 2 is greater than 1 and expect it to work.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Runners {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double  t1,
            t2,
            t3;



    System.out.print("Enter runner 1 name:");
    String name1;
    name1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter runner 1 time (in minutes):");
    String time1;
    time1 = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print(" Enter runner 2 name:");
    String name2;
    name2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter runner 2 time (in minutes):");
    String time2;
    time2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print(" Enter runner 3 name:");
    String name3;
    name3 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter runner 3 time (in minutes):");
    String time3;
    time3 = keyboard.nextLine();


    t1 = Double.parseDouble(time1);
    t2 = Double.parseDouble(time2);
    t3 = Double.parseDouble(time3);




    if(t1 > t2 && t1 > t3){
        if(t2>t3){
            System.out.print(" "+ name3 + "\n"+ name2 + "\n" + name1+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" "+ name2 + "\n" + name3 + "\n" + name1+ "\n");
        }
    }
    else if(t2>t1 && t2>t3){
        if(t1>t3){
            System.out.print(" " + name3 + "\n" + name1 + "\n" + name2+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name3 + "\n" + name2+ "\n");
        }
    }
    else if(t3>t2 && t3>t1){
        if(t2>t1){
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name2 + "\n" + name3+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" " + name2 + "\n" + name1 + "\n" + name3+ "\n");
        }
    }
    else if(t3==t2 || t3==t1){
        if(t2>t1){
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name2 + "\n" + name3+ "\n");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" " + name1 + "\n" + name2 + "\n" + name3 + "\n");
        }




}
    }
}
```